# Does Huawei u8160 support USB host?

Tags: cyanogenmod, usb-host-mode, huawei-u8160

I have a Huawei u8160(A. K. A Vodafone 858) which is running Cyanogenmod 7.2.

I was wondering if it supports USB host so I can connect a keyboard or a Flash drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read [this]: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1259739
After you flash the latest rom you could flash the usb host mode which is [here]: http://goo.im/devs/psyke83/roms/u8160/hotfixes

called usbhost1-cm-7-20120729-MADTEAM-u8160.zip

Enjoy.

Comment: sorry but the link is not found